# Symfony2: Undefined index notice after moving to server

Tags: image, apache, http, symfony, http-headers

I have tested my application on my localhost and on a hosted webserver. Now i have a new vserver where i installed all software manually. Now when i run my application, i get a strange error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: form_userprofile in /var/www/...
```

What i do in the controller there, is the following:

```
public function editProfileCheckAction(Request $request)
{
  $user = $this->getUser();

  $form = $this->createForm(new UsersType(), $user);
  $form->submit($this->getRequest()->request->get($form->getName()));
  $email = $this->get('request')->request->all()['form_userprofile']['email'];
```

In my console it shows me the following to send to the server:

```
  Request URL:http://../edit_check
  Request Method:POST
  Status Code:302 Found
Request Headers
  Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate
  Content-Length:1379
  Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryl33AbLp8NUbbGxaG
Request Payload
  ------WebKitFormBoundaryl33AbLp8NUbbGxaG
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_userprofile[firstname]"

  some
  ------WebKitFormBoundaryl33AbLp8NUbbGxaG
  Content-Disposition: form-data; name="form_userprofile[homecountry]"

  AC
```

And now, on the server, there is no content under 'Request Payload' and i get a 500.

In addition, it would be nice to know what 'boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryl33AbLp8NUbbGxaG' means?!

Would be nice if you could help me out! :)

Answer (score 0):

ok i have found the problem, gd was not installed.

so `apt-get install php5-gd` did the trick. sry for the inconvenience